# Is there any way to run a test script after each request in Postman Collection?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I am working on a Restful API that creates a new token after each request.
So, in Postman I am refreshing my token environment variable after each request in Tests like following:

```
pm.test("Successfull Login Test", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include('"result":"success"');
    var res = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set("token", res.token);
});
```

I wonder if it is possible to do this operation for all collection items?
I mean I want to say to Postman, run this script after every request.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not use the pre-request script?  Use this script, which is run before each script in Postman, to validate the token is set (or updated) and then set a variable (if this token is needed), and then your normal script can run and do the request and testing as you would expect?

Comment: Thank you Steven. API Changes token value every time. So I need a function after got the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a collection, and the collection (or folder) can also have tests that are run after every request.  [Postman Collections/Folder Testing](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-scripts/#testing-collections-and-folders).

[image: Collection Pre-Request Scripting]

[image: Collection Tests]

Comment: Hope it works for you, with the processing order that Postman uses, but it should be able to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you Steven! This is what exactly I am looking for. Actually, I tried and wrote a comment from mobile app yesterday, but now I cant see it. I hope this comment reaches you this time :)