# How to store a request JSON in a variable and use it in the mocked response body

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-mocks

I want to mock exact request values in response.

ex :

**request body**

```
{“username”:“google”,
“address” : {“city”:“CA”},
“contactNo”:“8274287844”
}
```

**response should be like this** : based on request i need to map exact values to same key(from request to response - mocking with example)

```
{“username”:“google”,
“address”:{“city”:“CA”}
}
```

I have tried adding changes in prescript

```
var reqBody= pm.request.body.raw
console.log(reqBody)
//console.log(req)
var json_verify = function(reqBody){ try { JSON.parse(reqBody); return true; } catch (e) { return false; }}
if(json_verify){
    var val = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw)
    var bol = true
    for(var key in val)
    {
     if(key === "username"){
       pm.globals.set("userName", key);
     }
   }
}
```

my example mocked response body like this :

`{"username":{{userName}}}`
or tried
`{"username":{{$userName}}}`
or tried

```
{"username":pm.globals.usrName}
```

but when i ran response body is coming as :

```
{"username":{{userName}}} or {"username":{{$userName}}} or {"username":pm.globals.userName}
```

expected output:

{"username":"google"}

please suggest me the possible ways. any help much appreciated.

Comment: any help pls ....

Comment: See my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758297/is-there-any-way-to-run-a-test-script-after-each-request-in-postman-collection/62776603#62776603). By using the pre-request script you can capture some data and test it after the process.  The same functionality exists on the individual request level as well.

Comment: @StevenScott i want to form the response using request body value. curently i am using prescipt and capturing values from req and setting to global variables using these variable in response object. but its not wrking. pls check my question i have specified clearly.

Comment: pls help me on this or is there any other tool that support this type situation

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. `{"username":{{$userName}}}` and `{"username":pm.globals.usrName}` will work. please follow this

> [Is there any way to run a test script after each request in Postman Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758297/is-there-any-way-to-run-a-test-script-after-each-request-in-postman-collection/62776603#62776603)

it will guide you through some basics

posted lately but to help any one who may face, this will helpful